# Project using Bluemix with node-RED and websocket - Client is a android device

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, ibm-cloud, intel-edison

As sketch link below I need help to do a websocket to control two DC motors in intel EDISON (connected to a i2c driver which in turn is connected to the intel Edison). ***First side:*** intel Edison/I2C DRIVER with python or C++library/2 motors/ BLUEMIX with node-RED and websocket. ***Second side:*** BLUEMIX and android with SDK.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gPdWq4OH-XbDJTdjUzM3pHdEk/view?pli=1)

Can anyone write about ideas/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but if you are asking how you can gather data from your Edison into Bluemix, than I can think of two things:

1. Install Node-RED in your Edison and use node-red-gpio to communicate to the I2C interface and then send the data to an MQTT (perhaps IBM IoT Foundation or any other MQTT) and then the app in Bluemix can read that MQTT topic.
2. Gather your data with your own scripts and connect your Edison directly to IBM IoT Foundation using a recipe https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/